# HLS Stream Using AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate TS Fragment Requests Missing Cookie Header

Tags: swift, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, avassetresourceloaderdelegate

I am using the `AVAssetResourceLoadingDelegate` to intercept all manifest requests for an HLS Manifest

```
let str = "examplehttp://example.com/path/to/master.m3u8?token=SOMETOKEN"
guard let url = URL(string: str) else { return }

let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
let loaderQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.LoaderQueue")
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(delegate, queue: loaderQueue)

let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
```

In the delegate I perform all the manifest requests myself using `URLSession` and return the responses back to the `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest`

```
// NOTE: dataRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest
dataRequest.respond(with: data)
loadingRequest.response = response
loadingRequest.finishLoading()
```

This stream is protected using a fairly standard auth process:

Request to master manifest is made with an appended token query param. The response to the master manifest includes a set-cookie header. Each subsequent request that has a domain specified on the set-cookie response header includes the cookie on its request headers.

What I am finding is that all requests made through the delegate do have the cookie added to the header but since the delegate cannot be used for TS segments the cookie is not being added.

Does anyone know of a way to force the `AVURLAsset` to always use the cookie header provided by the response to the master manifest for requests that are made outside of the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`?

Since I do provide the `URLResponse` back to `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest` and I know you can add cookies to a URLSession using the URLSessionConfiguration's `httpShouldAccpetCookies`, `httpCookieAcceptPolicy`, and `httpCookieStorage` properties. I don't think this is outside the realm of possibilities.

I am also aware of the `AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey` that can be added to the instantiation of the `AVURLAasset` but I do not have the cookie until a master manifest request is made.

Comment: Did you find anything new about this in the meantime? Or how did you actually resolve it? Facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Nothing new other than the answer below. We had to request cdn's to support query tokens on segment requests.

Answer (score 3):

Response From Apple:

> It is not possible to use the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate to capture
>   and modify the master/child manifests for an HLS playlist to set a
>   cookie header for the domain of the manifest URL. This is not
>   currently supported in AVFoundation.
>
> [The] only current support for cookies is the ability to use the
>   AVURLAsset AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey initialization option to allow the
>   AVURLAsset to use additional HTTP cookies for HTTP(S) requests. See
>   https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avurlassethttpcookieskey
>   for more information.
>
> Simply get your cookies and create a dictionary with the key value
>   pairs as shown below ( @{AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey : cookies} ), then
>   specify this dictionary in the AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:linkUrl
>   options:
>
> NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]
>   cookies];
>
> AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:yourURL
>   options:@{AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey : cookies}];
>
> AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
>
> AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
>
> Please note this only allows you to set cookies when the AVAsset is
>   created, and you can't then subsequently mutate these at a later time.
>
> Also, as discussed in the documentation, in HLS, many HTTP requests
>   (e.g., media, crypt key, variant index) might be issued to different
>   paths or hosts. In both of these cases, HTTP requests will be missing
>   any cookies that do not apply to the AVURLAsset URL.
>
> One "unofficial" solution that might work is to pass the playback
>   request through a reverse proxy which will allow you to intercept the
>   request, add headers, send it to the real server, and then extract the
>   headers from the response before returning it to the AVPlayer.